# Offline installation ImageMagick

Tags: centos, redhat, yum, rpm

I am trying to install ImageMagick into a RedHat 7 which is offline.

To do so, I've downloaded ImageMagick RPM along with it's dependencies using :

```
repotrack -p . ImageMagick
```

but also tried with

```
sudo yumdownloader --installroot=/home/RPM --resolve ImageMagick --releasever=6
```

or

```
sudo yumdownloader --installroot=/home/RPM --resolve ImageMagick --releasever=/
```

It downloads me respectively 288 and 213 packages.

---

For both of the results when I try to install them on my RedHat, I got an error :

---

Executing :

```
sudo yum localinstall *.rpm
```

[image]

---

Executing :

```
rpm -ivh --nodeps *.rpm
```

[image]

---

Of course at the end I end up with :

> ROOT@sv005849.info.ratp:/appli/ogp/DEPOT_COTEP/RPM/repotrack# convert
>   -bash: convert: command not found

---

What do I do wrong ? How can I install ImageMagick on my offline redHat please. i'm taking any solution

Comment: Please always post error messages as text, *never* as images, especially for any kind of shell output like in this case.

Comment: @Sven sorry I'll next time. Thank you for your input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you don't have the same packages installed on your offline server and the one where you are downloading your dependencies.

I wrote an extensive explanation in this answer on how to **simulate** the update on your online server to make sure you have all dependencies: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50683836/2082964